# Beautifying Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-idle

I have a pandas dataframe. I am using Python 3.8.2

Is there a program, or method to make the dataframe more visually pleasing? Rather than just plain text.

Comment: Check - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [dtale](https://pypi.org/project/dtale/).

> D-Tale is the combination of a Flask back-end and a React front-end to
>   bring you an easy way to view & analyze Pandas data structures. It
>   integrates seamlessly with ipython notebooks & python/ipython
>   terminals. Currently this tool supports such Pandas objects as
>   DataFrame, Series, MultiIndex, DatetimeIndex & RangeIndex.